# Javascript methods out of scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am very new to javascript and I am researching knockooutjs library to start using it in my application. I have declared a namespace and viewmodel with some methods. Everything is working as expected until I call OnTemplateChange. Then the addIp and  removeIp methods do not work any more.

I have declared a namespace in a separate file:

```
var omega = omega || {};
```

This is the code for my viewmodel in another file. I am getting Json data from the FranchiseData controller and I am using the mapping plugin to create viewmodel observable properties.

```
$(function () {
    omega.franchiseInfo = {}

    $.getJSON("FranchiseData", function (data) {
        //using the mapping plugin
        omega.franchiseInfo = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        //declare an observable array for some custom logic to handle when json data is received from the server
        omega.franchiseInfo.Ips = ko.observableArray([]);

        if (data.ServerIps.length === data.ServerPorts.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.ServerIps.length; i++) {
                omega.franchiseInfo.Ips.push({ ip: ko.observable(data.ServerIps[i]), port: ko.observable(data.ServerPorts[i]) });
            }
        }
        ko.applyBindings(omega.franchiseInfo);
    });

   onTemplateChange = function (value) {
    var template = $("#networks :selected").val();
    $.getJSON("FranchiseData", { network: template }, function (data) {
        omega.franchiseInfo = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        omega.franchiseInfo.Ips = ko.observableArray([]);         
}

save = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Save",
        type: "POST",
        //data: ko.toJSON({ folderName: FolderName }),
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) { alert("result") }
    });
}

addIp = function () {
    if (omega.franchiseInfo.Ips().length < 10) {
        omega.franchiseInfo.Ips.push({ ip: ko.observable(), port: ko.observable() });
    }

}

removeIp = function () {
    if (omega.franchiseInfo.Ips().length > 1) {
        omega.franchiseInfo.Ips.pop();
    }
}
)}
```

When onTemplateChange method is called I am doing the mapping again as I am not able to use the observable methods from the first Json call on page load. Moreover the addIp and  removeIp no longer work. I think I have problem with the scope and doing the mapping twice is wrong.

If i try to declare the methods of the franchiseInfo view model like this:

```
omega.franchiseInfo = {
        Ips: ko.observableArray([])
    };
```

The Ips array is undefined inside the `$.getJSON("FranchiseData", function (data)` scope.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am very stuck with this. If something is unclear I will give further explanation. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After $.getJSON( i would expect to end like }) or });

Also you already declared omega.franchiseInfo.Ips as an observableArray

So why don´t you make it empty like this
omega.franchiseInfo.Ips([])